# Do the apps purchased via SlideME.org give you notifications about available updates?

Tags: updates, notifications, alternative-markets

[SlideME](http://www.slideme.org/) is a website where you can purchase apps (useful for countries where Play Store does not support purchase yet).

Will I get a notification if their apps are updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SlideME Application Manager (SAM)](http://slideme.org/sam) will notify you if there's an update to the apps purchased from SlideME.

> SAM supports SlideME's Storage Locker. This allows you to re-download or upgrade Android applications you have previously purchased in case you lost or reset device.

Comment: when will it be released?